# <<access>> and <<use>> in UML Component diagrams

Tags: uml, component

How to decide if have to take the `<<access>>` or `<<use>>` notation for "-->" arrows in Component diagrams written in UML?

Comment: Could you please explain more? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The keyword «access» is used for private package imports.** The UML 2.4.1 spec says "A package import is shown using a dashed arrow with an open arrowhead from the importing namespace to the imported package. A keyword is shown near the dashed arrow to identify which kind of package import is intended. The predefined keywords are «import» for a public package import, and «access» for a private package import."[1]

**The keyword «use» is used to depict the use of an interface.** The UML 2.4.1 spec says "For displaying the full signature of an interface of a component, the interfaces can also be displayed as typical classifier rectangles that can be expanded to show details of operations and events." [2] and "A usage dependency is shown as a dependency with a «use» keyword attached to it." [3]

[1] UML Superstructure Specification, v2.4.1; page 112; http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Superstructure/PDF

[2] UML Superstructure Specification, v2.4.1; page 153; http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Superstructure/PDF

[3] UML Superstructure Specification, v2.4.1; page 139; http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Superstructure/PDF